# Does Codeception support automatic rollback in unit tests for Symfony?

Tags: codeception

I've looked through the Codeception documentation and I've seen that it mentions automatic rollback/database cleanup for functional tests, but I haven't seen anything about unit tests.

This is my configuration for unit tests, but there are visible database changes after I run the unit test suite.

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration
#
# Suite for unit or integration tests.

actor: UnitTester
bootstrap: bootstrap.php
modules:
  enabled:
    - Asserts
    - Doctrine2:
        depends: Symfony
        cleanup: true
    - \Helper\Unit
```

Does Codeception support cleanup for unit tests? If so, how do you get them working?

Comment: Does tested code use instance of Doctrine from symfony container?

Comment: @Naktibalda How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Remaining database changes were made by tests that use database, but don't use Doctrine2 module, because they execute queries using a differrent database connection.

To fix this issue, you must identify tests are doing that (visible database changes should help to do that, look for that data in tests) and make them use Doctrine object retrieved using `$I->grabService('doctrine');`.

Comment: These are unit tests, so I don't receive the `$I` object.

Comment: `$this->tester->grabService('doctrine');`

Comment: `[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method UnitTester::grabService`

Comment: Right, it belongs to Symfony module, so you have to either enable Symfony module with `part: services` parameter to reduce size, or implement your own helper method containing `return $this->getModule('Doctrine2)->em`;